# Bing Map for Android

Tags: android, bing-maps

we are planning to use **bing maps** for **Android** device. We are not using **google maps** as we have premium licences for Bing and hence we prefer to use that. But after few days of search I was not able to find any thing substantial about how to use **bing maps** in android phones. One option I tried was to use `WebView` and then display the bing maps but it was not as intuitive as what we could get if it was a `MapView`. So if is possible to get bing maps in the same way as we get the **google maps** in the `MapView` with default support for panning and zooming etc.

Comment: Well, you're gonna have to write the code for it? Write code that downloads the segments from the Bing server, handles moving and scaling them?

Comment: Well you are going to have to create a BingMapView then, that will send requests to download map tiles and display them, just like the Google MapView does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updates :** bing map deprecated  **AndroidSDK**

---

Rather than start coding from scratch now, I'd wait for the Bing Maps Android SDK from inknowledge (developed by Ricky Brundritt - one of the Bing Maps MVPs), due out later this month:
http://www.inknowledge.co.uk/Products/BingMapsAndroidSDK.aspx

**Edit: 15th March 2011**
The Android Bing Maps SDK has now been released. You can download it from:
http://bingmapsandroidsdk.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot !!. This is really useful . lets wait and see what is in the store. By the time i will try to find more alternatives and post here if i find anything really good

Answer (score 1):

**Updates :**
I also wanted to include the bing map in my app but they have deprecated it in  `AndroidSDK`

**see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn894107.aspx) link for proper use of bing map**

---

> This project is now deprecated, use the Bing Maps V7 AJAX control to
>   create cross platform applications

There is also a note on the official website

> This SDK was designed to work with **Android 2.x** devices. **Newer 3.x** and
>   **4.x Android devices** have bugs in the WebViewer control which causes poor performance with this SDK. This SDK is built on top of the **Bing
>   Maps V7 AJAX** control and as such can also be used to create web based
>   application that work on Android devices. In addition it can also be
>   used with PhoneGap (http://phonegap.com) if you want to create a
>   native application. This is the recommended development route as this
>   will allow all new functionality in `Bing Maps v7` to become instantly available to your application.