# Using Bing Maps Android SDK as a library

Tags: android, bing-maps

I am going to implement an in-application maps in my Android application, so my first thought was: **Google Maps**.

However it does not support caching - if user closes application, all loaded maps are deleted. Then I found **Bing Maps** which supports caching.

There is Bing Maps `Android SDK`, but it is delivered as a whole Android application. I do not know at all how to use it.

Are there any tutorials, examples, etc showing how to use it with custom application as a build-in activity ?

Comment: see this answer for updates  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198332/bing-map-for-android/31065390#31065390

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SDK](http://bingmapsandroidsdk.codeplex.com/) is an Android project, so:

1. Download it from http://bingmapsandroidsdk.codeplex.com/
2. Extract it
3. Import it into Eclipse using `File -> Import -> Existing Projects into Workspace`
4. Right click the project and choose `Run As -> Android Project`

It shows how you can use the `BingMapView`.

However, I get a message on the map that says

> Invalid Credentials. Sign up for a developer account at: http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers

After that, you're on your own. Perhaps check out their [discussion board](http://bingmapsandroidsdk.codeplex.com/discussions).

Comment: i got the same invalid Credential message, but where to set the Credential details...

Comment: According to that page the project is now "deprecated".

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about Bing, but you might like to consider Osmdroid which does support caching and offline tile sources

[Osmdroid Home Page](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/)

It works much like the Google Maps API.