# How to use Bing Maps for Android API/SDK

Tags: android, sdk, apk, bing-maps

I've started looking through the Bing Maps for Android API/SDK and I'm fairly certain that I'm ready to start a new project using Bing Maps. I've downloaded the SDK from [here](http://bingmapsandroidsdk.codeplex.com/), but I'm not quite sure how I would start a new project with it.

I've tried exporting the SDK as a .jar file and adding it to my new project, but I run into collision errors with the SDK's resources. Is there any other way to use the SDK or do I have to have multiple copies of the SDK to modify every time I want to use Bing Maps for Android?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Bing Maps Android SDK as a library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312437/using-bing-maps-android-sdk-as-a-library)

Comment: I read the question, it simply shows how to download the SDK (really a complete Android project). It doesn't really explain how to start a new project for use with the API/SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create it as a library project by going to Project Properties > Android and check "Is Library".