# How to integrate bing maps in my android app

Tags: android, bing-maps

I would like to ask, CAN YOU integrate Bing Maps within an Android app? Secondly, if possible, exist there a tutorial?

Comment: same question asked here :
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491686/how-well-does-bing-maps-api-integrate-with-android-app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198332/bing-map-for-android