# How can I use the bing map on my app

Tags: android, bing-maps

My purpose is to show the **New York** map on my app.

First I download the `BinMapsAndroidSDK1.5`. Then, I import it into eclipse and run it as an android application. The result is the logo and "`Bing Maps Android Sdk`".

Who can tell me if i missed something?
What should I do to achieve my purpose?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198332/bing-map-for-android/31065390#31065390

Answer (score 0):

you have to connect to the Internet, I guess you didn't do it. But after that there's an alert about account on bing and that's also my problem so if anybody could help with that I'd be very pleased...

edit:
I found this one helpful, hope you'll too ;) good luck :D http://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2012/03/24/how-to-integrate-bing-map-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this SDK for integrating Bing Maps in Android:
http://blogs.bing.com/maps/2011/03/31/bing-maps-android-sdk-available-on-codeplex/

Its a cool API which is easy to use.